# Ruby one to one and one to many mapping

Tags: ruby

Within a folder, I have the following two text files:

sample_1.txt

```
# Planned on June 21st 2016
# Proposed by John Take (jfc43t)

auth = crt\jfc43t, crt\cz8jio, crt\czr5o2
perm = jio\uy6y0n, crt\lp8n77, crt\cz8jio
taped = jio\uy6y0n
```

sample_2.txt

```
# Planned on June 22nd 2016
# Proposed by rae ball(po09iv)

div = crt\mzrt7r, crt\mzi01r, jio\buy7xd
perm = crt\r9myl7, jio\buy7xd, crt\soi8wh
read = crt\mzrt7r
```

I want to read these files and print to a log file in the following manner:

out.log

```
Name crt\cz8jio
Deleted from row id : auth, perm

Name crt\lp8n77
Deleted from row id : perm

Name crt\mzrt7r
Deleted from row id : div, read
```

I used arrays and map improperly. I also tried hashes, but I'm not sure how to use them in my code.

This is my incomplete code, the best I have tried:

```
........
...........  
  id_files.each do |file_name|
      text = File.read(file_name)
      replace = text.gsub( /#{Regexp.escape(line)}/, '' )#this is for top loop
       unless text == replace
        text.each_line do |li|
          if li.match(/#{Regexp.escape(line)}/) then #line is a variable substitution from top loop
            pool << li.split(" ")[0]          
          end

        end 
        File.open('E\users.txt', 'a') { |rem| 
        rem.puts "Removed from: #{file_name}"
        rem.puts "Removed user : #{line}"
        rem.puts "Removed from row :#{pool.join(' and ')}"
        }
        .....
        ......
```

Comment: It would help if you added some code that at the very least parsed these rows, or gave a code-form sketch of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @tadman : My bad, forgot to add it. I have added the code snippet. Pls. excuse if its very nooby.

Comment: Always good to see how you've set things up so others can help build on that and move forward.

Comment: @tadman: My apologies, I have put up my code in the question (edited). Thanks. I'm not sure how to proceed with the mapping.Thanks again for your time looking into my issue.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]" and the linked pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine for one hard coded file just rewrite it according your needs.

```
text = File.read('in.log')
result = {}
text.each_line do |line|
  if /\A(?<id>[^=]+) = (?<names>.*)$/ =~ line
    names.split(', ').each do |name|
      result[name] ||= []
      result[name] << id
    end
  end
end

File.open('out.log', 'a') do |f|
  result.each do |key, value|
    f.puts "Name #{key}"
    f.puts "Deleted from row id : #{value.join(', ')}"
    f.puts "\n"
  end
end
```

Input:

```
# Planned on June 21st 2016
# Proposed by John Take (jfc43t)

auth = crt\jfc43t, crt\cz8jio, crt\czr5o2
perm = jio\uy6y0n, crt\lp8n77, crt\cz8jio
taped = jio\uy6y0n
```

Output:

```
Name crt\jfc43t
Deleted from row id : auth

Name crt\cz8jio
Deleted from row id : auth, perm

Name crt\czr5o2
Deleted from row id : auth

Name jio\uy6y0n
Deleted from row id : perm, taped

Name crt\lp8n77
Deleted from row id : perm
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I have modified according to my requirements.

Comment: @voltas No problem, glad to help you.